# How to access enable property of the children of a uipanel?

Tags: matlab, properties, panel, children, matlab-guide

Suppose that I have a GUI like this
[image]
and I want all the children of each panel be disabled at first and then when I check the radio button at the top of a panel the children of that panel will be enabled.
Can you suggest me how can I do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that `get()` and `set()` aren't just scalar, they're perfectly happy with vectors of handles. The question is, how to obtain and use those vectors? There's a couple of approaches here, you can either manually create a vector of handles for each panel:

```
function gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
[...]
handles.panel1controls = [handles.edit1, handles.edit2];
handles.panel2controls = [handles.edit3, handles.checkbox1, handles.edit9];
[...]
guidata(hObject, handles);
end

function radio1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (get(handles.radio1, 'Value') == get(handles.radio1, 'Min'))
    set(handles.panel1controls, 'Enable, 'Off');
else
    set(handles.panel1controls, 'Enable, 'On');
end
end

function radio2Callback(...
```

or just do it dynamically - this way you save the initial setup, and don't have to remember to update it if you add/remove controls later, but have less fine control e.g. you disable the text labels too, which can look a bit rubbish on some platforms:

```
function radio1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (get(handles.radio1, 'Value') == get(handles.radio1, 'Min'))
    set(get(handles.panel1, 'Children'), 'Enable, 'Off');
else
    set(get(handles.panel1, 'Children'), 'Enable, 'On');
end
end

function radio2Callback(...
```

Now, that still needs a callback function per radio button, which can end up being a ton of duplicated code. Let's get clever and associate the handles with the buttons themselves via `UserData`, allowing them all to share one nice tidy generic callback function:

```
function gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
[...]
set(handles.radio1, 'UserData', [handles.edit1, handles.edit2]);
set(handles.radio2, 'UserData', [handles.edit3, handles.checkbox1, handles.edit9]);
[...]
end

function radio_common_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (get(hObject, 'Value') == get(hObject, 'Min'))
    enable = 'Off';
else
    enable = 'On';
end
set(get(hObject, 'UserData'), 'Enable', enable);
end
```

or for the 'dynamic' whole-panel approach,

```
function gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
[...]
set(handles.radio1, 'UserData', handles.panel1);
set(handles.radio2, 'UserData', handles.panel2);
[...]
end

function radio_common_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if (get(hObject, 'Value') == get(hObject, 'Min'))
    enable = 'Off';
else
    enable = 'On';
end
set(get(get(hObject, 'UserData'), 'Children'), 'Enable', enable);
end
```

The simplest way to have everything start disabled is to set it that way in GUIDE, however there's no reason we can't instead do it programmatically at the end of `OpeningFcn()`. In fact, why not do it all in one go with another level of concatenation:

```
set([handles.panel1controls, handles.panel2controls, ...], 'Enable', 'Off');
```

Not even GUIs are exempt from the Matlab rule of "try to vectorise everything"...